# Spring/Jersey creating new service objects every time I make a rest call

Tags: spring, rest, jersey

Every time I make a rest call, localhost:8080/user/1, it creates a new user service object instead of using the one that was created during server start up. I am using Jersey with Spring.

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd"
    default-autowire="byName"
    >

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
 <context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.gigenginecore.platform.dataaccess.impl" /> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gigengine.dataaccess"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gigengine.dataaccess.impl"/> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gigenginecore.platform.service" /> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gigengine.service" />  
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gigenginecore.provider" />   

</beans>
```

/////code snippet of UserService class , I even tried to force the scope to be singleton.

```
@Service 
@Scope("singleton") 
@Path("/user")
public class UserService extends AbstractUserService {


///from my web.xml
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>   
           <param-value>com.gigengine.service,com.gigenginecore.platform.service, com.gigenginecore.provider</param-value> 
        </init-param> 
        <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param> 
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet> 
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

/////
All the DAOs get instantiated properly and injected into the user service class at start up but when I call the service endpoint itself it creates a new UserService class with a DAO being null.

Is there something I need to do to grab the one that was created at startup? Not sure why it creates a new instance when its a "Spring" singleton.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Use `com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet` instead of `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer` when using Jersey with Spring. See http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/contribs/jersey-spring/com/sun/jersey/spi/spring/container/servlet/package-summary.html